# The upper bound of edges of the generalized cactus graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

In graph theory, a cactus is a connected graph in which any two simple cycles have at most one vertex in common. Equivalently, it is a connected graph in which every edge belongs to at most one simple cycle.

The following is well known about the upper border for cactus graph class.

**Theorem 1.** The maximum number of edges in a simple $n$-vertex cactus $G$ is $\left\lfloor{\frac{3(n-1)}{2}}\right\rfloor$.The bound is achieved by a set of $  \lfloor (n − 1)/2 \rfloor $ triangles sharing
a single vertex, plus one extra edge to a leaf if $n$ is even.

The theorem can be found on page 160 of West's book. The proof content can also be easily referred to the answers in its appendix.

- West D B. Introduction to graph theory[M]. Upper Saddle River: Prentice hall, 2001.

I want to think about a broader graph class than the cactus class. **It is a connected graph in which every edge belongs to at most $k$ simple cycle**. I do not know whether a definition of this graph class exists. We'll temporarily call it the $k$-cactus graph.
So we have a similar problem with the upper bound of the edge of the $k$-cactus graph.

**Problem  1.** What is the maximum  number of edges in a simple $n$-vertex $k$-cactus graph?

In particular, $k=2$ is what we care about most.

**Appendix:** The four proofs of Theorem 1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello! Do you have any results about these 2-cactus graphs in which every edge belongs to at most 2 simple cycles?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen  Thank you very much for your interest in this question. I did prove a result privately last year.  I'll have time to add this proof later.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Due to the answer being too long, we have written an article, which should soon be uploaded to arXiv (if not, and you're interested, I will send it to your email address, hoping I can find your correct email). There are more questions worth further exploration in it, and perhaps there is a possibility for collaboration.

Comment: Sounds good! $\phantom{...}$

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen See https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.08039. We have just posted it on arXiv.

Answer (score 1):

For $k=2,3,4$, we solved this question. But for large $k$, we may need more deep tools.

More details can be seen in *L.C.Zhang, Y.Q. Huang,  On the sizes of generalized cactus graphs, Discrete Applied Mathematics, 348 (2024) 184-191* [doi.org/10.1016/j.dam.2024.01.043](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dam.2024.01.043)